# One ion-select-option is changing all ion-select-options - Angular/Ionic 4+

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Heres a summary of what I'm trying to achieve:

> Create cards with 'dynamic' drop downs to select a 'product' and add those cards as an object of each product. E.g: 3 cards will display. And when i 'Add to card' a card, in my check out will be 3 objects in a JSON Object.

My Problem, It's amateur level but here:

> When I change one drop down on one card, all the other drop downs change as well. EG: I changed *dropdown A* on *card 1* to 'Chicken' then *card 2* and *card 3* changes its *dropdown A* to Chicken as well. But they are meant to stay on default 'choose a product' value.

Here's the example code for what I'm working on:

**products.serivce.ts** -- Has dummy Data to fill in the dropdowns .

```
export class ProductsService{

  private category = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Sea Food' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Pasta' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Sushi' }
  ];

  private foodName= [
    { id: 1, name: 'Fish-A', category_id: 1, category_name: 'Sea Food' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Fish-B', category_id: 1, category_name: 'Sea Food' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Fish-C', category_id: 1, category_name: 'Sea Food' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Pasta-A', category_id: 2, category_name: 'Pasta' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Pasta-B', category_id: 2, category_name: 'Pasta' },
    { id: 6, name: 'RawFish-A', category_id: 3, category_name: 'Sushi' },
    { id: 7, name: 'RawFish-B', category_id: 3, category_name: 'Sushi' }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  getCategory() {
    return this.category;
  }
  getFoodName() {
    return this.foodName;
  }

}
```

**home.page.ts**

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  category = [];
  foodName= [];

  public selectedFoodCategory : any[];

  public sFood: any;

  cardArrayOfObjects = [];
  name = '';
  constructor(
    private cartService: ProductsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.category = this.cartService.getCategory();
    this.foodName = this.cartService.getFoodName();
  }

   setFoodValues(sFood) {
    this.selectedFoodCategory  = this.foodName.filter(district => district.category_id == sFood.id)
  }

  getNumberOfCards() {
    this.cardArrayOfObjects .length = 0;
    const name = Number(this.name);
    for (let i = 1; i <= name; i++) {
      let obj = {
        Name: [`Card Number ${i}`],
      };
      this.cardArrayOfObjects.push(obj);
    }
  }

}
```

**home.page.html** -- And Lastly, the HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center ion-justify-content-center">
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="name" clearInput type="number" class="ion-padding"
      placeholder="How many orders would you like?"></ion-input>
    <ion-button primary (click)="getNumberOfCards()">Get Started</ion-button>
  </ion-row>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let cardObj of cardArrayOfObjects">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Category</ion-label>
              <ion-select (ionChange)="setFoodValues(sFood)" [(ngModel)]="sFood">
                <ion-select-option [value]="sFood" *ngFor="let sFood of category ">{{sFood.name}} </ion-select-option>
              </ion-select>

            </ion-item>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card-header>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

I removed every thing i deemed not necessary to shorten this question. There isnt any console, compilation errors. Any help and/or advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all of your ion-select has the same ngModel of `sFood`. Since there are multiple products, you need to have a form model that represents that. If you're going to use `[(ngModel)]="sFood"` you may need to use the index as well on it and make sFood an array.

```
*ngFor="let card of cardArrayObjects; let i = index"
```

and something like `[(ngModel)]="sFood[i]"` if you make sFood an array.

Comment: Thanks man, tried it earlier but its making the sFood an Array that has messed me up. Appreciate it.